# Is it possible to calculate number factorial at compile time, but without enums

Tags: c++, templates

I want to calculate factorial at the compile-time. I found some way to solve the problem, but I want to know if there any another solution for this problem without using `enum` s. Here the solution using `enum` s.

```
#include <iostream>
template <int n>
struct fact
{
    enum{value = n*fact<n-1>::value};
};

template<>
struct fact<1>
{
    enum{value = 1};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << fact<10>::value;
}
```

If there is no another solution, please describe why the `enum` s are must.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming, it is [a sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Compile-time_class_generation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While there are alternative notations, It's written that way because more compilers accept that enum-style notation. The language supports const integral-type class members with an inline initialization, but some compilers aren't compliant with the standard in that regard. On compilers that are compliant in this regard, the following works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
template <unsigned int n>
struct fact
{   
    static const unsigned int value = n*fact<n-1>::value;
};  

template<>
struct fact<0>
{   
    static const unsigned int value = 1;
};  

int main()
{   
    std::cout << fact<10>::value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: fact<0> should probably be the base case (0! = 1)

Comment: the same solution can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

Comment: The solution in the wikipedia article uses the enum version. The use of enums are not a must here.

Comment: @Adam: You're right: fact<0> should be the base case. I just took the OP's code and got rid of the enums.

Answer (score 7):

Replace,

```
enum{value};
```

with,

```
static int const value; // or unsigned int
```

`enum`s are must because they suppose to be resolved at compile time. Which assures that whatever result you calculated must have been done at compile time. Other such type is `static int const` (means any integral type).

To illustrate:

```
enum E {
 X = strlen(s); // is an error, because X is a compile time constant
};
```

Comment: Enums are not a must here. The language allows static const members of integral type to be given an initial value. Enums are a must only on non-compliant compilers (which are in great abundance apparently).

Comment: @iammilind thanks for the answer. I would like to know why it is must write `static int const` why `static int` is not acceptable.

Comment: @Samvel, because `static int` is not resolved at compile time; thus even if you do it. It want be a compile time constant.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use static const members:

```
template <unsigned int n>
struct fact { static const unsigned int value = n * fact<n-1>::value; }
```